# How to show background image in React component div?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a Header functional component with a div assigned to the Header className. That div has a background image but it is not rendering. The dev tools tell me the div isn't being assigned the Header className. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

[image]

What I've checked: 
• if I imported the CSS file and assigned the className to the div. 
• if I'm assigning the correct path to url image.
• if background-size value should be cover or contain.
• if background-image key should be backgroundImage

APP.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

HEADER.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Header.css';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Header}>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

HEADER.css

```
.Header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: "url('../../Images/horseshoebend.jpg')";
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
}
```

The results should show a background image.

Comment: you are using opaque colors so you will see nothing as the gradient is covering the image

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the gradient for now but the background image is still not showing.

Comment: What are you using to do the actual importing? [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)?

Comment: Try `console.log(classes)`. Is `Header` a property on `classes`?

Comment: Thank you FrankerZ, your suggestion reminded me that I first need to enable Create-React-App to enable CSS modules. I found an alternative solution, and renamed my CSS file to Header.module.css. That got it to work! Also, I removed the double quotes that were wrapping background-image: "url()".